# "In month year" versus "In year month"

Tags: dates

I find that "in May 2012" is used more often than "in 2012 May" by far. Is the latter ungrammatical?

Comment: Neither fits basic grammar rules very well, but the second form is, to most English speakers, "weird", whereas the first is readily accepted.

Comment: 'Grammar' is best not mentioned when discussing most formulaic usages. 'Acceptability' is the better term. And the less weird-sounding, usually the more acceptable.

Comment: And "proper" use would be "... in May, 2012 ..."

Comment: Thanks for the comments! Hot Licks, any source for the "proper" use? I have found some website (http://www.grammarbook.com/punctuation/commas.asp) that says there should be no comma.

Answer (score -1):

Month/day/year is the most common way of expressing a date in written and verbal language, which is why most of us have experienced screwing up our birthdate on some websites and forms that call for day/month/year or some other format. This is not, however, a grammatical issue; it is one of common usage.

"On May 12, 1985, many users on this site were born." (note the two commas)

Comment: "May 12, 1985" OR "12th of May, 1985"

Comment: This is true of US English. Other places have differing norms, and they tend to be rather inconsistent. I would personally write _12 May 1985_. But certainly never, ever _*12 1985 May_, which seems to be what the asker is implying.

Comment: Thanks, but this is not quite what I asked. Often one only wants to specify the month but not the day.

Comment: `Month/day/year is the most common way of expressing a date in written and verbal language` Mainly in the US. I'm aware your answer is focusing on English, but e.g. UK, Australia and New Zealand all prefer day/month/year. [Here you can find a map](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Date_format_by_country) that shows day/month/year to be the most common by far.